# Nuget Push always returning 404 (Not Found)

Tags: github, package, nuget

I've tried to publish a nuget package to my GitHub Packages account but in all cases I'm having the 404 error.
I've followed as requested on the GitHub's site:

```
nuget source Add -Name "GitHub" -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[MyAccount]/index.json" -UserName [MyUserName] -Password GH_TOKEN
```

It throwed me an error saying to add an api key.

So I created a Personal Access Token and set the api key:

```
nuget setapikey [MY_PAT_TOKEN] -Source "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[MyAccount]/index.json"
```

But when trying to push again I had:

> "Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages
>   service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the
>   appropriate scopes configured."

So I created another token with the necessary scopes:
 - read:packages 
 - write:packages
 - delete:packages
 - repo

I deleted the source and the api key and started the steps above again, with the new token, but I had the 404 error, saying that the source was not found.

So I've tried a lot of options... changing package name, changing source name, and a bunch of other things, but with the same result.

So I read this on the GitHub's website:

> "When you publish a package, by default GitHub Packages uses the
>   package name to determine the GitHub repository containing the
>   package. For example, a package named odata-client would be published
>   to the OWNER/odata-client repository. If you would like to change the
>   repository containing the package, or publish multiple packages to the
>   same repository, you can include the URL to the GitHub repository in
>   the repository field of the package's .nuspec file."

As I'm using .NET Core 3.0 so I changed the csproj including:

```
<RepositoryUrl>https://nuget.pkg.github.com/[MyAccount]/Common</RepositoryUrl>
<RepositoryType>git</RepositoryType>
```

But this time I had a 400 (Bad Request)

And I tired some variations for the above url: ending with index.json, ending without index.json, ending with common, etc... But always have Bad Request error.

So I deleted this configurations and tryied again: 404 (Not Found)

I don't know what to do any more. There are someone that can help me with that? What am I doing wrong? It lacks some configuration?

Answer (score 21):

I had same issue. For me it was wrong Repository Url in nuget package. I would advise you to check that RepositoryUrl is set and it is a valid url of existing repo.

Comment: I'd just like to reiterate this answer! Look for any typos, leading/trailing chars etc.

Comment: This was the solution for me, just repacking seems like a fake solution/answer

Comment: This was my solution as well. I'm really surprised at how terrible the error message is when the RepositoryUrl is set incorrectly.

Answer (score 3):

I have been fixed the same error setting my repository URL:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!--Others configurations values-->
    <RepositoryUrl>https://github.com/GITUSERNAME/REPOSITORY-PATH**</RepositoryUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I am using dotnet core and setting this configuration in .csproj

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, my solution was to give all "Repo" permissions to the token.
PS: my Repo was private