# Unable to push github package for nuget (404)

Tags: github, nuget, github-package-registry

I am unable to push a nuget package to GitHub

The following question is nearly identical

[Publishing and Consuming GitHub Package Repository with NuGet: Unable to load the service index error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59445987/publishing-and-consuming-github-package-repository-with-nuget-unable-to-load-th)

The answer was very helpful as it indicated that the GitHub documentation was out of date.  So I followed the revised instructions and still no joy.

I try to push with...

```
nuget push -source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany/index.json .\bin\Release\mynugetpackage.1.0.0.nupkg -apikey xxxaaabbb
```

and the error I get is...

```
Pushing mynugetpackage.1.0.0.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany'...
  PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany/
  NotFound 
https://nuget.pkg.github.com/mycompany/ 471ms
```

which seems to indicate that the mycompany GitHub package repository does not exist.  But the GitHub organization mycompany certainly exists. It seems as though I need to initialize the package repository for mycompany, but I can't find any documentation on how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is apparently you cannot push packages to repositories that are private.  As soon as I turned the visibility on my repository public, I could push a package.

This seems like a bug.  Certainly nowhere in the documentation does this restriction appear.

You should be able to push packages to private repositories.

*UPDATE*

It turns out the real problem was the scope of my personal access token.  The scope was set to read and write packages but repo scope also required to push a package to a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

this may be an issue with github.com
last week I was able to publish to ttps://nuget.pkg.github.com but today it gives the error described above

I have experienced a similar issue last month with pushing to the GitHub docker registry, it was intermittent failing about 8/10 times

Github actions log:

```
2021-01-21T21:34:45.3916558Z ##[section]Starting: Request a runner to run this job
2021-01-21T21:34:45.8756042Z Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in current repository that matches the required labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
2021-01-21T21:34:46.0149753Z Can't find any online and idle self-hosted runner in current repository's organization/enterprise account that matches the required labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
2021-01-21T21:34:46.2004629Z Found online and idle hosted runner in current repository's enterprise account that matches the required labels: 'ubuntu-latest'
2021-01-21T21:34:46.3573580Z ##[section]Finishing: Request a runner to run this job
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3282662Z Current runner version: '2.276.0'
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3308509Z ##[group]Operating System
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3309244Z Ubuntu
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3309623Z 18.04.5
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3309934Z LTS
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3310385Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3310766Z ##[group]Virtual Environment
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3311214Z Environment: ubuntu-18.04
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3311652Z Version: 20201210.0
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3312271Z Included Software: https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/ubuntu18/20201210.0/images/linux/Ubuntu1804-README.md
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3312886Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3314036Z Prepare workflow directory
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3501965Z Prepare all required actions
2021-01-21T21:34:54.3511197Z Getting action download info
2021-01-21T21:34:54.6103985Z Download action repository 'actions/checkout@v2'
2021-01-21T21:34:56.5627897Z Download action repository 'booxmedialtd/ws-action-parse-semver@v1'
2021-01-21T21:34:58.3019389Z Download action repository 'roryprimrose/set-vs-sdk-project-version@v1'
2021-01-21T21:34:59.1877480Z Download action repository 'Rebel028/publish-nuget@v2.6.0'
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7995996Z ##[group]Run actions/checkout@v2
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7996438Z with:
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7996838Z   repository: SomeCompany/dotnetlib
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7997482Z   token: ***
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7997761Z   ssh-strict: true
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7998063Z   persist-credentials: true
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7998351Z   clean: true
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7998616Z   fetch-depth: 1
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7998881Z   lfs: false
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7999152Z   submodules: false
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7999421Z env:
2021-01-21T21:34:59.7999782Z   PACKAGE_ID: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:34:59.8000168Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2300965Z Syncing repository: SomeCompany/dotnetlib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2301730Z ##[group]Getting Git version info
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2302608Z Working directory is '/home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib'
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2366579Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2518653Z git version 2.29.2
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2541336Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2549508Z Deleting the contents of '/home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib'
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2557721Z ##[group]Initializing the repository
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2562551Z [command]/usr/bin/git init /home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2643082Z Initialized empty Git repository in /home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/.git/
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2655569Z [command]/usr/bin/git remote add origin https://github.com/SomeCompany/dotnetlib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2699895Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2700600Z ##[group]Disabling automatic garbage collection
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2705024Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local gc.auto 0
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2744609Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2749309Z ##[group]Setting up auth
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2757117Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2021-01-21T21:35:00.2796014Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3303803Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3319220Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3590923Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local http.https://github.com/.extraheader AUTHORIZATION: basic ***
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3639230Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3639608Z ##[group]Fetching the repository
2021-01-21T21:35:00.3652890Z [command]/usr/bin/git -c protocol.version=2 fetch --no-tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules --depth=1 origin +141b682a377522b2dee30e48768f71d2fcd61024:refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7274685Z remote: Enumerating objects: 12, done.        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7275111Z remote: Counting objects:   8% (1/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7275486Z remote: Counting objects:  16% (2/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7275832Z remote: Counting objects:  25% (3/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7276200Z remote: Counting objects:  33% (4/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7276548Z remote: Counting objects:  41% (5/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7276902Z remote: Counting objects:  50% (6/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7277241Z remote: Counting objects:  58% (7/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7277583Z remote: Counting objects:  66% (8/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7277945Z remote: Counting objects:  75% (9/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7278283Z remote: Counting objects:  83% (10/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7278985Z remote: Counting objects:  91% (11/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7279334Z remote: Counting objects: 100% (12/12)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7279698Z remote: Counting objects: 100% (12/12), done.        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7280083Z remote: Compressing objects:  11% (1/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7280456Z remote: Compressing objects:  22% (2/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7280816Z remote: Compressing objects:  33% (3/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7281171Z remote: Compressing objects:  44% (4/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7281574Z remote: Compressing objects:  55% (5/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7281934Z remote: Compressing objects:  66% (6/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7282301Z remote: Compressing objects:  77% (7/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7282653Z remote: Compressing objects:  88% (8/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7283020Z remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9)        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7283390Z remote: Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.        
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7329472Z remote: Total 12 (delta 0), reused 8 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7448310Z From https://github.com/SomeCompany/dotnetlib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7460101Z  * [new ref]         141b682a377522b2dee30e48768f71d2fcd61024 -> v1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7479921Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7484449Z ##[group]Determining the checkout info
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7502460Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7503178Z ##[group]Checking out the ref
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7504309Z [command]/usr/bin/git checkout --progress --force refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7638510Z Note: switching to 'refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc.1'.
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7639229Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7639861Z You are in 'detached HEAD' state. You can look around, make experimental
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7640341Z changes and commit them, and you can discard any commits you make in this
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7640820Z state without impacting any branches by switching back to a branch.
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7641103Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7641464Z If you want to create a new branch to retain commits you create, you may
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7642105Z do so (now or later) by using -c with the switch command. Example:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7642360Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7642804Z   git switch -c <new-branch-name>
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7643001Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7643274Z Or undo this operation with:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7643454Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7643696Z   git switch -
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7643860Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7644217Z Turn off this advice by setting config variable advice.detachedHead to false
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7644514Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7644756Z HEAD is now at 141b682 ...
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7645185Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7685657Z [command]/usr/bin/git log -1 --format='%H'
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7727367Z '141b682a377522b2dee30e48768f71d2fcd61024'
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7894232Z ##[group]Run booxmedialtd/ws-action-parse-semver@v1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7894594Z with:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7895013Z   input_string: refs/tags/v1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7895356Z   version_extractor_regex: \/v(.*)$
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7895630Z env:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7896004Z   PACKAGE_ID: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.7896376Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8414806Z ##[group]Run roryprimrose/set-vs-sdk-project-version@v1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8415184Z with:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8415451Z   version: 1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8415737Z   projectFilter: **/*.*proj
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8416020Z env:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8416382Z   PACKAGE_ID: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8416754Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8898305Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8902954Z Finding projects matching **/*.*proj
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8903728Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8904768Z Updating project files with the following version information
2021-01-21T21:35:00.8905926Z Version: 1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9147733Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9148630Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9150282Z Found project at /home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9214137Z Updating Version with the value 1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9338470Z ##[group]Run Rebel028/publish-nuget@v2.6.0
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9338809Z with:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9339233Z   PROJECT_FILE_PATH: SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9339802Z   PACKAGE_NAME: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9340196Z   VERSION_STATIC: 1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9340487Z   TAG_COMMIT: false
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9340998Z   NUGET_KEY: ***
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9341382Z   NUGET_SOURCE: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9341752Z   INCLUDE_SYMBOLS: true
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9342089Z   VERSION_REGEX: ^\s*<Version>(.*)<\/Version>\s*$
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9342396Z   TAG_FORMAT: v*
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9342684Z   THOW_ERROR_IF_VERSION_EXISTS: false
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9342970Z env:
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9343339Z   PACKAGE_ID: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9343717Z ##[endgroup]
2021-01-21T21:35:00.9775191Z executing: [dotnet nuget add source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/index.json --name=default --username=myusername --*** --store-password-in-clear-text]
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7366050Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7367012Z Welcome to .NET 5.0!
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7368084Z ---------------------
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7368567Z SDK Version: 5.0.101
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7368847Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7369182Z Telemetry
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7369688Z ---------
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7370951Z The .NET tools collect usage data in order to help us improve your experience. It is collected by Microsoft and shared with the community. You can opt-out of telemetry by setting the DOTNET_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT environment variable to '1' or 'true' using your favorite shell.
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7371688Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7372790Z Read more about .NET CLI Tools telemetry: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli-telemetry
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7373918Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7374511Z ----------------
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7376693Z Installed an ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7377623Z To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only).
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7378410Z Learn about HTTPS: https://aka.ms/dotnet-https
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7378989Z ----------------
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7379654Z Write your first app: https://aka.ms/dotnet-hello-world
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7380378Z Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7381101Z Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7381671Z Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7382498Z Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7383338Z --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7384192Z Package source with Name: default added successfully.
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7384535Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:06.7385018Z executing: [dotnet nuget list source]
2021-01-21T21:35:07.1692751Z executing: [dotnet nuget enable source default]
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5291185Z Registered Sources:
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5292077Z   1.  nuget.org [Enabled]
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5292659Z       https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5293185Z   2.  default [Enabled]
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5293747Z       https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/index.json
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5294201Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5294807Z Package source with Name: default enabled successfully.
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5295227Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5295832Z Project Filepath: SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5297066Z Version: 1.0.0-rc.1
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5297721Z Package Name: SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5298527Z This is GPR, changing url for versioning...
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5299334Z https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/download/SomeCompany.DotNetLib/index.json
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8163314Z Status code: 200: OK
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8185105Z This version is new, pushing...
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8191136Z ✨ found new version (1.0.0-rc.1) of SomeCompany.DotNetLib
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8191771Z NuGet Source: https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8196344Z executing: [dotnet build -c Release SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj]
2021-01-21T21:35:08.4553400Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
2021-01-21T21:35:08.4554845Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2021-01-21T21:35:08.4556123Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:11.6713234Z   Determining projects to restore...
2021-01-21T21:35:26.7150347Z   Restored /home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj (in 13.99 sec).
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6009835Z   SomeCompany.DotNetLib -> /home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/bin/Release/net5.0/SomeCompany.DotNetLib.dll
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6269565Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6270770Z Build succeeded.
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6271286Z     0 Warning(s)
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6271770Z     0 Error(s)
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6272149Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6272697Z Time Elapsed 00:00:25.92
2021-01-21T21:35:34.6481756Z executing: [dotnet pack --include-symbols -p:SymbolPackageFormat=snupkg --no-build -c Release SomeCompany.DotNetLib.csproj -o .]
2021-01-21T21:35:34.9172951Z Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 16.8.0+126527ff1 for .NET
2021-01-21T21:35:34.9173542Z Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
2021-01-21T21:35:34.9173794Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:36.4807333Z   Successfully created package '/home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.nupkg'.
2021-01-21T21:35:36.4848834Z   Successfully created package '/home/runner/work/dotnetlib/dotnetlib/SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.snupkg'.
2021-01-21T21:35:36.5067101Z Generated Package(s): SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.nupkg, SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.snupkg
2021-01-21T21:35:36.5069263Z executing: [dotnet nuget push *.nupkg -s default -k *** --skip-duplicate ]
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3597726Z Pushing SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany'...
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3598984Z   PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3599634Z   NotFound https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/ 338ms
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3600286Z error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3600703Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3600985Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3601498Z Usage: dotnet nuget push [arguments] [options]
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3601816Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3602568Z Arguments:
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3603118Z   [root]  Specify the path to the package and your API key to push the package to the server.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3603564Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3603940Z Options:
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3604746Z   -h|--help                      Show help information
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3606487Z   --force-english-output         Forces the application to run using an invariant, English-based culture.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3607832Z   -s|--source <source>           Package source (URL, UNC/folder path or package source name) to use. Defaults to DefaultPushSource if specified in NuGet.Config.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3608849Z   -ss|--symbol-source <source>   Symbol server URL to use.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3609757Z   -t|--timeout <timeout>         Timeout for pushing to a server in seconds. Defaults to 300 seconds (5 minutes).
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3610641Z   -k|--api-key <apiKey>          The API key for the server.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3611427Z   -sk|--symbol-api-key <apiKey>  The API key for the symbol server.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3612676Z   -d|--disable-buffering         Disable buffering when pushing to an HTTP(S) server to decrease memory usage.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3613901Z   -n|--no-symbols                If a symbols package exists, it will not be pushed to a symbols server.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3614890Z   --no-service-endpoint          Does not append "api/v2/package" to the source URL.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3615882Z   --interactive                  Allow the command to block and require manual action for operations like authentication.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3617012Z   --skip-duplicate               If a package and version already exists, skip it and continue with the next package in the push, if any.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3617477Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3619162Z /home/runner/work/_actions/Rebel028/publish-nuget/v2.6.0/index.js:44
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3621869Z ##[error] error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3625811Z         throw new Error(msg)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3626167Z         ^
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3626367Z 
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3626876Z Error: error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3627925Z     at Action._printErrorAndExit (/home/runner/work/_actions/Rebel028/publish-nuget/v2.6.0/index.js:44:15)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3628867Z     at Action._pushPackage (/home/runner/work/_actions/Rebel028/publish-nuget/v2.6.0/index.js:95:18)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3629749Z     at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/home/runner/work/_actions/Rebel028/publish-nuget/v2.6.0/index.js:151:30)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3630357Z     at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:215:7)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3630839Z     at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1184:12)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3631353Z     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3712765Z Post job cleanup.
2021-01-21T21:35:37.4744452Z [command]/usr/bin/git version
2021-01-21T21:35:37.4819055Z git version 2.29.2
2021-01-21T21:35:37.4865812Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp core\.sshCommand
2021-01-21T21:35:37.4915283Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'core\.sshCommand' && git config --local --unset-all 'core.sshCommand' || :
2021-01-21T21:35:37.5248078Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --name-only --get-regexp http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader
2021-01-21T21:35:37.5274602Z http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2021-01-21T21:35:37.5286498Z [command]/usr/bin/git config --local --unset-all http.https://github.com/.extraheader
2021-01-21T21:35:37.5335820Z [command]/usr/bin/git submodule foreach --recursive git config --local --name-only --get-regexp 'http\.https\:\/\/github\.com\/\.extraheader' && git config --local --unset-all 'http.https://github.com/.extraheader' || :
2021-01-21T21:35:37.5770506Z Cleaning up orphan processes
2021-01-21T21:35:37.6317787Z Terminate orphan process: pid (2841) (dotnet)
```

As you can see:

```
2021-01-21T21:35:07.5299334Z https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/download/SomeCompany.DotNetLib/index.json
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8163314Z Status code: 200: OK
2021-01-21T21:35:07.8185105Z This version is new, pushing...
```

the registry exists and a list of versions can be retrieved

```
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3597726Z Pushing SomeCompany.DotNetLib.1.0.0-rc.1.nupkg to 'https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany'...
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3598984Z   PUT https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3599634Z   NotFound https://nuget.pkg.github.com/SomeCompany/ 338ms
2021-01-21T21:35:37.3600286Z error: Response status code does not indicate success: 404 (Not Found).
```

but the push fails

Comment: Just now figured out what the problem was (at least with my package)...the repository was private.  As soon as I turned it public, I could push the package.

Comment: 10 days ago I was able to push with a private repo. Hopefully that gets fixed soon as I can't make my repos public

Comment: GitHub support just got back to me.  My problem was the scope of the personal access token.  Has to include both repo and read/write packages.

Answer (score 0):

You many need to check that your Repository Url in your project is set correctly. [Nuget Push always returning 404 (Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59119353/nuget-push-always-returning-404-not-found/71652822#71652822)

I had this error and was able to solve it by fixing my repo url.